# Is the use of rownum safe to update a table with incremented IDs on Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, auto-increment, rownum

Similar to [MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989342) I want update (fill) an empty column with incremental values -- with *Oracle*. I.e. after

```
ALTER TABLE data ADD
(
  id  number
);
```

I want for all records the `ID` column to receive unique values. After that I will enable *Not Null* and *unique* constraints to make it a *primary key*.

I came up quickly with

```
UPDATE TABLE data SET id = rownum;
```

but I have a bad feeling about this. It works in my tests as expected, but an example is no proof :-)

**Is it safe to use `rownum` in this manner in an `update`-statement?**

Comment: @knagaev That is a different issue, and not related to this. I would have to fill the data cells of the existing rows, anyway.

Comment: Why different? You can use "UPDATE TABLE data SET id = seq.nextval" You get unique values as you wish. And it will be transaction-safe solution.

Comment: @knagaev Oh, thanks for the explanation, I have to try that out (I am curently not near the DB). I assumed `seq.nextval` would only be evaluated once.

Comment: Please take a closer look at sequences in Oracle - it is one of important things. They work very fast and keep you from potential problems with transaction isolation.

Comment: @knagaev Yes, I don't like `max(id)+1` either :-) I tried it, it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I've never had a problem with that method, but enabling not null and unique constraints does not make it a primary key -- adding a primary key constraint makes it a primary key ;)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your method is safe. If not, you would be notified if unique constraint fails :-).

Bullet-proof method is the following:

```
lock table data in exclusive mode;

merge into data t
using (select t.rowid rid, t.rownum id from data t) s
on (t.rowid = s.rid)
when matched then update set
  t.id = s.id;

commit;
```

Comment: The `merge` is not necessary, a plain update will do exactly the same thing.

Comment: It's the `update` in the initial question. That will be perfectly OK (your `merge` will do exactly the same thing - just a bit more complicated).

Comment: What are you bullet-proofing it against?

Comment: Against simultaneous modification of the same table by another session (which may results in nulls in `id` column).  Unique constraint should be also set before (or instead of) commit.

Comment: Well the lock makes it more robust in that sense, but not the MERGE, I think.

Answer (score -3):

No, it is not safe, as ROWNUM is pseudocolumn. Means it does not guarantee the sequence especially when using with ORDER BY. If you must, then use ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY your_field) instead of ROWNUM. You may also use PL/SQL to update your table once in the loop.

Comment: It **is** safe for the intended purpose.

Comment: If there was some implied correlation between "your_field" and the primary key value then it wouldn't really be a very good "meaningless" primary key, I think.

Comment: At least your answer shows me that my concerns were not totally unfounded.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - it is never safe and advisable to use pseudocolumns if you have a choice between them and sequence and function such as row_number(). What is the point of using rownum if you have row_number()? Stubbornness? Not thinking about future impacts? Can anyone be abs sure about future impacts? This was/is my point and opinion.

Comment: The `row_number()` function is probably be more expensive (=slower) due to the ordering that is required. `rownum` can be evaluated "on the fly" without any additional overhead. And in this case it **is** safe to use.

Comment: To alter table once it does not really matter what to use. And it is good to have difference of opinions. This way one learns more and think twice...